# Best way to observe concurrentmap in java

Tags: java, concurrency

It's a producer-consumer setup (multithreaded chatserver) and I have a concurrentmap where I put named printwriter

```
ConcurrentMap<String, PrintWriter> allNamedPrintwriters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
allNamedPrintwriters.put(content, pw);
```

I would like the main-server to be the one to close the connections based on changes in the allNamedPrintWriters-map (being maintained by the consumer).
I don't want any of the other threads to do the job. So they do not have access to the socket - only the readers/writers.
Is there an obvious solution to this? A kind of trigger that could be observed?

Comment: Perhaps add the [JavaFX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) library (actually, [*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io/) implementation) to your project, passing your `ConcurrentMap` object to [`FXCollections.observableMap`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableMap(java.util.Map)) to get an [`ObservableMap`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableMap.html). I’ve not done this, so investigate for yourself. Study the source code to be sure it does not introduce thread-safety issues with your concurrent map.